# Scala XML Pattern matching and Attributes

Tags: xml, scala, pattern-matching

First of all: I'm at Scala 2.8

I have a slight issue while using pattern matching on XML elements. I know I can do something like this:

```
val myXML = <a><b>My Text</b></a>
myXML match {
    case <a><b>{theText}</b></a> => println(theText)
    case _ =>
}
```

This is the sort of example I find everywhere on the net and in both of my Scala books. But what if I want to match on an XML element depending on an attribute?

```
val myXML = <a><b type="awesome">An awesome Text!</b></a>
myXML match {
    case <a><b type={textType}>{theText}</b><a> => println("An %s text: %s".format(textType, theText))
    case _ => 
}
```

The compiler will throw an `error: in XML literal: '>' expected instead of 't'` at me, indicating that I cannot use attributes because the compiler expected the element tag to be closed. If I try to match an XML element with a fixed attribute, without curly braces, the same error raises.

So my question is simple: How can I do such a match? Do I have to create an `Elem` for the match instead of using those nice literals? And if: What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Handling attributes is way more of a pain that it should be. This particular example shows, in fact, that Scala doesn't deconstruct XMLs the same way it constructs them, as this
syntax *is* valid for XML literals. Anyway, here's a way:

```
myXML match { 
  case <a>{b @ <b>{theText}</b>}</a> => 
    println("An %s text: %s".format(b \ "@type", theText))
}
```

Comment: I guess it will be even more painful to have a case where only nodes where the type attribute has a certain value matches. :-( Am I right?

Comment: @Malax Not really, just add `if b \ "@type" == Text("whatever")` before `=>`. Or, alternatively, `if (b \ "@type").toString == "whatever"`.