# scala xml pattern matching on same-name elements

Tags: scala

suppose I have the following xml:

```
val xml = 
  <countries>
    <country isoCode="AU">Australia</country>
    <country isoCode="GB">Great Britain</country>
  </countries>
```

How do i pattern match the  element with isoCode="AU" ? I have come up only with the following solution:

```
xml match {
  case <countries>{cs @ _*}</countries> => {
    for(c <- cs) {
      c match {
        case cnode @ <country>{name}</country> if (cnode \ "@isoCode").toString == "AU" => println("I like " + name)
        case _ => Unit
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610191/scala-xml-pattern-matching-and-attributes your solution seems to be the best current practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mtsz is correct this is simply how its done in Scala Xml.  If you are open for alternatives then Scales provides a direct xpath syntax (and string based via Jaxen) and pattern matching over attributes:

```
import scales.utils._
import ScalesUtils._
import scales.xml._
import ScalesXml._

import TextFunctions.value

val xml = 
  (<countries>
    <country isoCode="AU">Australia</country>
    <country isoCode="GB">Great Britain</country>
  </countries>).asScales.rootElem

val couldContainAU = top(xml). *("countries"). 
    \*("country"). 
    \@{ a => a.name == ("isoCode"l) && a.value == "AU"}.\^

couldContainAU.foreach{ country => println( "got " + value(country) ) }

// or collect all isoCodes via pattern matching

val IsoMatcher = ElemMatcher("country", "isoCode")

for{ countries <- top(xml) * "countries"
     country <- countries \* "country"
 } elem(country) match {
  case IsoMatcher(elem, Attr(iso) :: Nil) => println(iso+" => "+value(country))
  case _ => println("oops")
}
```

NB

```
\@{ a => a.name == ("isoCode"l) && a.value == "AU"}
```

will be possible via

```
\@("isoCode") .*@(_.value == "AU")
```

in the next RC as well.