# scala node match case

Tags: scala

this works:

```
<a>apple</a>

node match {
  case <a>{contents}</a> => "It's an a: "+ contents
  case _ => "It's something else."
}
```

---

how can i modifiy this example, so that it only matches a node with a tag "a" and attribute id=2:
something as follows:

```
<a id="2">apple</a>

node match {
  case <a id="2">{contents}</a> => "It's an a: "+ contents
  case _ => "It's something else."
}
```

but this does not compile.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610191/scala-xml-pattern-matching-and-attributes).

Comment: Take a look at this [post][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610191/scala-xml-pattern-matching-and-attributes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```
node match {
  case a @ <a>{contents}</a> if (a \ "@id").text == "2" => "It's an a: " + contents
  case _ => "It's something else."
}
```

Comment: it's a pity that it is not well integrated.

Answer (score 3):

One more way, just for the sake of it.

```
<a id="2">apple</a> match {
  case Node("a", Attribute("id", Text("2"), _), Text(contents)) => contents
}
```

Doesn't work for multiple attributes, though.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you need full XPath support to write queries like "a[id='2']"

[Scala scales](http://code.google.com/p/scala-scales/) is one of available options.

But in addition to [Philippe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9484071/210905) i can suggest this query

```
import scala.xml.Text
val node = <a id="2">apple</a>
(node  \\"a" \"@id").text match {
  case "2" => "It's an a: "+ (node \\"a").text
  case _ => "It's something else."
}
```